# AdWords invalid gclid htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, google-ads-api

i keep getting an error from Google with the parameter gclid.

Here is my htaccess:

```
ReWriteRule ^([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&spage=$3&ppage=$4&pppage=$5&ppppage=$6&gclid=$7
```

With this, i have urls like: https://domain.com/us/blog/whatever-deeplink-name

Can anyone help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding [QSA,L] to the end of the line solved my issue.

```
ReWriteRule ^([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&spage=$3&ppage=$4&pppage=$5&ppppage=$6&gclid=$7 [QSA,L]
```